# Can someone explain this word?

Tags: ancient-greek, xenophon

I'm reading Ανάβασις by Ξενοφών. I came across this sentence:

"--ἀλλ᾽ ἔστι μὲν ἡμῖν, ὦ ἄνδρες, ἀρχὴ **πατρᾐα** πρὸς μὲν μεσημβρίαν μέχρι οὗ διὰ καῦμα οὐ δύνανται οἰκεῖν ἄνθρωποι, πρὸς δὲ ἄρκτον μέχρι οὗ διὰ χειμῶνα:"

This is Kyros talking, the leader of the army approaching Babylon. The word "πατρᾐα" is absent from Wiktionary and Perseus and is translated, in the version I've obtained, as "my father's empire". It looks a lot like "fatherland" or something. I also searched on "πατρεία" etc. in Wiktionary and Perseus. Nothing came up.

In πατρᾐα the mark above η is in fact a smooth breathing mark, not an accent. Suggesting that maybe this is in fact two words stuck together. Can anyone explain it?

Comment: Looks like a typo; the actual word is πατρῴα. If it were a case of crasis you'd still expect to see an accent somewhere.

Comment: Thanks. I should have added that I did a bit of googling before adding the question, and this passage, with this word, comes up... maybe they're all getting it from the same source which originally misspelled it...

Comment: The [Greek Wikisource](https://el.wikisource.org/wiki/%CE%9A%CF%8D%CF%81%CE%BF%CF%85_%CE%91%CE%BD%CE%AC%CE%B2%CE%B1%CF%83%CE%B9%CF%82/%CE%91) has the error, and it claims to be based on Marchant's OCT, [which does not](https://archive.org/details/xenophontisopera03xeno/page/n43/mode/2up) (and also nothing in the critical apparatus, so it's not a manuscript issue). Probably their fault.

Comment: Yeah, my guess is that it's an OCR error that no one proofread. If you Google the words right before it, you'll see that the more respectable sites have πατρῴα and the ones with the error are regular people's sites. They probably never even noticed the mistake. @Cairnarvon, you should make that an answer.